# Is transient rendering, as described below, possible with Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

By transient rendering I mean to render a series of images, each of specific ray length from the camera (counting also multiple bounces into the total length). Would it be possible with Cycles?

For example,
Below is a normal rendering.

[image: Static]

This is its transient rendering

[image: Transient]